# SQLITE, Выбрать совпадения в таблице и извлечь оттуда id

Tags: sql, sqlite

У меня есть 5 кандидатов: А, Б, В, Г, Д.
Мне нужно извлечь всех кто голосовал за кандидатов как user N (Голос может быть положительный и отрицательный). Например user 1111 голосовал за А, Б, В и против: Г, Д). Теперь нужно выбрать всех, кто голосовал так-же минимум за 1 из этих кандидатов.

Желательно отсортировать по количеству совпадений, т.к. кто может точь в точь по голосам совпасть, а кто то может проголосовать положительно только за 1 из этих 3 кандидатов (А, Б, В).

Я вижу такое решение:

```
candidats = SELECT candidat_id FROM votes WHERE user_id = 1111;
SELECT user_id FROM votes WHERE candidat_id in candidats
```

DDL:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS votes(
user_id INTEGER,
candidat_id INTEGER,
vote INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, candidat_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (candidat_id) REFERENCES candidats (id) ON DELETE CASCADE)""")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.user_id, COUNT(t1.candidat_id)
FROM votes t1, votes t2
WHERE t2.user_id = 1111
  AND t1.user_id != 1111
  AND t1.candidat_id = t2.candidat_id 
  AND t1.vote = t2.vote 
GROUP BY t1.user_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Логика происходящего.

Берём две копии таблицы. Из второй оставляем только запись "эталонного" юзера (`t2.user_id = 1111`). Из первой выбираем все записи для других юзеров (`t1.user_id != 1111`) такие, что голос за некоего кандидата (`t1.candidat_id = t2.candidat_id`) у них совпадает (`t1.vote = t2.vote`). И считаем, сколько таких совпадений (`COUNT(t1.candidat_id)`) для каждого "другого" юзера (`GROUP BY t1.user_id`).

Comment: Спасибо. Не могли бы вы немного объяснить ответ, я плохо знаю БД.

Comment: @ДавидШико Добавил в ответ.